# how to download twilio for python 2.7.9 for sending texts

Tags: python-2.7, twilio

I'm unable to download and choose the right Twilio version to text messages and SMS for python version 2.7.9. 
i have tried t download it using instructions but I'm unable to do so. i also have python 3.7.3 on my windows 10 PC

Comment: ::wave:: Hi @parth!  We'll need some more detail on what specifically you've tried and what errors you're seeing in order to help you.  Maybe check out this article on how to ask a good question on StackOverflow and then update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using these two tutorials;

How to setup environment
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-set-up-your-python-and-flask-development-environment#install-flask-and-the-twilio-python-sdk

How to Send and Receive SMS Using Python;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knxlmCVFAZI